# I would like to become a blockchain developer

Tags: blockchain

I would like some advice before deciding to become a blockchain developer. Any comment would be really appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: It is better to ask such question on social networks like reddit, twitter or forums about crypto development.

Answer (score 2):

Blockchain development is now understood as three main areas:

1. Development of the blockchain- and DLT-protocols and their software implementation
2. Development of crypto-exchanges
3. Development of distributed applications based on blockchain and DLT platforms (for example, based on Ethereum/Quorum, Hyperledger Fabric, Corda and so on)

I work in area 3 - in the medium term (2-3 years) it looks the most demanded in the enterprise market (trade finance, supply chains, insurance, digital assets and so on) in terms of investments and staff shortages.